# Are Vanyel's descendants in later books?

Tags: valdemar

Is Darkwind from the *[Mage Winds](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41447-valdemar-mage-winds)* trilogy related to Vanyel, the last Herald Mage, in any way? Perhaps a great-grandchild?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

According to [the wiki](https://valdemar.fandom.com/wiki/Vanyel):

> Descendants: Elspeth, Herald Kris, Firesong

Elspeth was in both the *Mage Winds* and *Mage Storms* series.

There is no indication that [Darkwind](https://valdemar.fandom.com/wiki/Darkwind) is a descendant, although of course, his marriage to Elspeth now makes him an in-law of sorts.